# Profiling a Lightswitch application?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, profiler, visual-studio-lightswitch, red-gate-ants

We are in the requirements stage of a Lightswitch based app. I was looking for code profiling support  for lightswitch applications and have tried Ants 7.1 which we already have licence for, but it does not appear to work when the .xap file is chosen for profiling (choosing type as a Silverlight 4 app). Profiler stops immediately after "starting" and nothing really happens. Red gate mentions [here](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content/ANTS_Performance_Profiler/help/7.3/APP_Silverlight)  about support for out of browser silverlight apps.

Looks like VS.NET code profiler also does not work as expected with Lightswitch.  Is there a code profiler that really works with Lightswitch app? Since lightswitch is basically a silveright app, is there a silverlight configuration/support issue that fails profiling the .xap file?

P.S: I used [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LightSwitch-HTML-Preview-b34b9311) LightSwitch sample from Microsoft to check.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to have a look at this post: http://ayende.com/blog/4604/profiling-lightswitch-using-entity-framework-profiler It suggests this product: http://efprof.com/